# Was the Great Pattern concept borrowed?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, mythology, robert-jordan

I already know that the Wheel of Time idea originates in real-world concept, Kalachakra (the author [admitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_time#Literature) it).

But what about the Pattern - as a textile metaphor for fate, space, time and universe (and everything)? Are there signs that it was borrowed from the myths or preceding fiction works?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I wonder also about phrases such as "the fabric of time", which is term from our age that also applies to the Great Pattern!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Greek and Norse mythology, respectively the [Moirai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai) and [Norns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norns) weave the threads of fate. From scanning those wikipedia articles I see there also is a Roman equivalent to them; [Parcae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcae). While not exactly a "textile", I am guessing that Robert Jordan at least took some inspiration from them, especially as one of the main characters in the story has a name very close to the collective name for one of these groups of "fate-spinners".

[Some further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaving_%28mythology%29) reveals a lot of goddesses and myths associated with weaving, but none which is as strongly associated with fate as the ones above.

Comment: Great answer, thanks, I totally forgot about Moirai/Parcae.

Comment: Hmm ... I wonder if the name Moiraine was based on the Moirai? Never thought of that before!

Answer (score 2):

It is a common theme throughout history.

> Dion, a Tragedy: And Miscellaneous Poetry ... - Page 30
>
> George Ambrose Rhodes - **1806**
>
> To the tried wisdom of the chosen few, Th' approved of his country;
>   not himself, Arrest th' enacting and enforcing power, T' embody the
>   vagaries of his brain, And **weave the fate of empires on his loom**
>   To what strange shape he pleases.
>
> https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rqlgAAAAcAAJ

Answer (score 1):

In the preceding fiction category, there's Piers Anthony's ["With a Tangled Skein"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_a_Tangled_Skein) (1985) from his Incarnations or Immortality series. The characters there are strongly based on the Greek fates, and the threads of life and tapestry of fate are key elements.